# Using Object map arrow function to reformat objects in an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have following code: `snapshot.val()` Object coming from firebase database and grabs names using map function.

```
database.ref('/destinations').once('value', function (snapshot) {

    const locations = snapshot.val();

    const destinations = Object.keys(locations).map(key =>
        locations[key].name
    )
    console.log(destinations);
    // returns ["California", "Nevada"]

    dispatch(
        get_destinations({
            ...destinations
        })
    );
})
```

I wanted to reformat results so it can look like this:

```
const destinations = [
                { label: 'California', value: 'california' },
                { label: 'Nevada', value: 'nevada' },
]
```

Comment: can you share what's their in locations ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const destinations = Object.keys(locations).map(key =>
    ({
        label: locations[key].name,
        value: locations[key].name.toLowerCase()
    })
)
```